# How to use overloads in a custom messagebox (myMSGBOX.SHOW(overloads)

Tags: wpf, overloading, messagebox

I have created my own messagebox window which is working however this is how I currently use it:

```
var msgbox = new msgbox("Please confirm patients phone number with them before proceeding");
msgbox.ShowDialog();
```

I want to be able to use it this way:

```
MessageBox.Show("Choose an Estimated Time of Arrival");
```

This is first of all so i can just replaceAll MessageBox with msgbox.  I have lots in my application and now that I have my own custom messagebox it will be so much easier to replace this way rather than replacing with the first set of code.

The issue is I can't figure out how to have the overloads in the showDialog section?

Comment: What is the return type of your ShowDialog method?

Comment: hmmm ok i dont have a showdialog method... is that what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably more than one solution but I would create a new `MyMessageBox` class with `Show` method and I would create `msgbox` inside this method.

```
public sealed class MyMessageBox
{
    public static bool? Show(string messageBoxText)
    {
        var msgbox = new msgbox(messageBoxText);
        return msgbox.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Then just replace all `MessageBox` with `MyMessageBox`.

`System.Windows.MessageBox.Show` returns `MessageBoxResult`, so you can create `Show` method that returns also `MessageBoxResult`.

```
public sealed class MyMessageBox
{
    public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText)
    {
        var msgbox = new msgbox(messageBoxText);
        msgbox.ShowDialog();
        return MessageBoxResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Comment: RIGHT I didnt know I can just have teh SHOW method!!!
Thanks for that Ill try it out and then put this as the answer.